# Compare 2 worksheets with duplicates in excel 2003/2007 or google docs

Tags: excel, duplicates

I have a excel document with a 2 worksheets.
In each of worksheets, there is a 2 columns.
First column contain product numbers, second contain product price.

1st SHEET            2nd SHEET
    PN    Price          PN         Price 
    406  189.03     9360     59 
 9280   39.52       9365     59 
 9365   54            9380     59 
43006   76           25960   6.99 
43007   33           43037   118.99 
43027   83           43118   122.99 
43028   8             43140   197.99 
43029   388         43220   265 
43037   113.99    43221   269 
43044   235         43222   190.49

First worksheet have 10 000 records, second 6 500 records.

I want to find all product numbers that are in bouth worksheets,

1st SHEET            2nd SHEET
    PN    Price          PN         Price 
    406  189.03     9360     59 
 9280   39.52       ***9365     59*** 
 ***9365   54***            9380     59 
43006   76           25960   6.99 
43007   33           ***43037   118.99*** 
43027   83           43118   122.99 
43028   8             43140   197.99 
43029   388         43220   265 
***43037   113.99***    43221   269 
43044   235         43222   190.49

remove it all products numbers with the prices that are not duplicate
to have after that this:

1st SHEET            2nd SHEET
    PN    Price          PN         Price 
  ***9365   54***             ***9365     59*** 
***43037   113.99***     ***43037   118.99***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Prepare unique list of PN entries**
Into `ColumnA` of a new sheet, copy `PN` details with header from `1st SHEET` and append to that `PN` details without header from `2nd SHEET`.
Might as well sort.
Advanced Filter `Column`A with Copy to another location, Copy to: `B1` and Unique records only selected. OK. (Remove Duplicates is not quite as reliable as Advanced Filter.)

**Lookup**
Name your ranges `range1` and `range2` respectively in the source sheets.
In `C2` of new sheet enter: `=VLOOKUP($B2,range1,2,FALSE)`and copy across to `D2`.
In `D2` change `1` to `2`.
In `E2` enter `=C2=D2`.
Copy `C2:E2` down as required.

**Select**
Filter sheet on `ColumnE` for `#N/A` and delete visible rows.
Unfilter.

**Tidy up**
Select sheet, Copy and Paste, Paste Special, Values.
Delete `ColumnE` and `ColumnA`.
Save.

Comment: in ***C2***, ***D2*** and ***E2*** i have #NAME?

Comment: I don't have Name Manager under Formulas,
I have a Insert > Name > Define,
and there I can define range1 as a =range1!$A:$A,
and range2 as a =range2!$A:$A

Comment: I added and B column for raneg1 and range2 and is working :)